# Programmatically check is bluetooth device activated on WindowsCE 5.0

Tags: windows-mobile, bluetooth

Is there a "nice" method to do this or I should try to open connection and if it fails I will assume that the device is not activated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the OpenNETCF.Net.Bluetooth DLL, if you've got that then you can simply check

```
OpenNETCF.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.Mode
```

Comment: Actually it was InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.BluetoothRadio.PrimaryRadio.HardwareStatus;

but there is the elegant solution